# Word 2013: Bullets don't appear when creating bullet list

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, bullets

In one particular word document (.docx in Word 2013) I keep encountering an issue where I'm unable to create bulleted lists, and I've tried everything I can think of to make the bullets appear.

**Behaviour**

When I select the block of text and press any 'bullet' style, the text indents (as if bulleted), but no bullet shows. If I try copying and pasting the line of text into an existing bullet list, it causes the bullet in the existing list to disappear. I've tried changing every font or paragraph setting I can think of which may be impacting this.

Here are two separate bulleted lists with the same style applied, the former with my setting problem and the second functioning normally:

[image: missing bullet]

The paragraph's *Style* has been correctly set to 'List Paragraph', which all of the bulleted lists have, and I can change this style to another type and then back to 'List Paragraph' and still the bullet won't show. Even after selecting a **bullet type**, clicking back on the bullet dropdown shows the current type as 'None'.

**Workaround**

I've come across this issue in three separate sections of the document, and can bypass it by re-typing the text somewhere else and then deleting the impacted section of the document, but I want to understand the setting which is preventing my lists from working.

Comment: This is only happening in this one document? All other documents are working as expected? Have you tried copying the content of this document into a new document?

Comment: I've only encountered the behaviour in particular areas of one document, and haven't seen it in any others yet. When copying the content to a new document the behaviour persists.

Comment: Probably the bullet exists but is not shown properly. Check the document in the the print preview and see if the bullet is there.

Comment: If you place the cursor in the place where the bullet should be and click, what happens? Does it look like what happens if you do the same for one of the other list items (except for the fact that the bullet isn't visible, of course)? Does Word 'think' there's a bullet there? If you select the whole paragraph, including the paragraph mark, and then press Ctrl+Spacebar to clear all formatting, does anything happen? If your document is based on a template, have you tried reapplying the template?

Comment: @cnread - when I click, it just brings me to the front of the line of text. When I click on an actual bullet in another paragraph, it selects the bullet, so no Word doesn't 'think' there's a bullet there. Clearing the formatting removes all formatting from the line but keeps the indent (all the **indent stops** have moved forward along the ruler). I'm not using a document template. It's bizarre to me because I encounter the same issue at different places in the document, and not just at one isolated point.

Comment: Clearing the formatting just removes any character formatting, so it wouldn't do anything to the indents. (I was thinking that white font color had somehow become applied to the ¶ mark, which would cause the bullet to turn white; that has happened to me before.) Even if you're not using your own custom template, you're still using the default Normal template. Reapplying that might help.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else is having the issue (I had it with Word 2019 Office 365 for Mac): I realised that for me the problem was being caused by page breaks. If I hit enter then I could create a bullet list on the line above, just not for the line that included the page break. I hope this helps!